# NLTK Wordnet: lemma_names vs similar_tos

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet, synonym, lemmatization

NLTK WordNet can generate synonyms of a given word with the `lemma_names` and `similar_tos` methods:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
for ss in wn.synsets("small"):
    print(ss.name())
    print("Synonyms:", ss.lemma_names())
    print("Synonyms:", [sim.name().split('.')[0] for sim in ss.similar_tos()])
```

Here is an extract of the printout:

```
small.a.01
Synonyms: ['small', 'little']
Synonyms: ['atomic', 'bantam', 'bitty', 'dinky', 'dwarfish', 'elfin', 'gnomish',
'half-size', 'infinitesimal', 'lesser', 'micro', 'microscopic', 'miniature',
'minuscule', 'olive-sized', 'pocket-size', 'puny', 'slender', 'small-scale',
'smaller', 'smallish', 'subatomic', 'undersize']
minor.s.10
Synonyms: ['minor', 'modest', 'small', 'small-scale', 'pocket-size', 'pocket-sized']
Synonyms: ['limited']
```

How are the synonyms returned by `lemma_names` different from those by `similar_tos`?

When should we use one method or the other?

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems from reviewing the source code that `lemma_names` get the lemmatized names for that synset which `similar_tos` get all *related* synsets using the `&` relation operator (intersection).

Here are the relevant bits of [source code](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet):

Lemma Names

```
def lemma_names(self, lang='eng'):
    '''Return all the lemma_names associated with the synset'''
```

Similar Tos

```
def similar_tos(self):
    return self._related('&')

def _related(self, relation_symbol):
    get_synset = self._wordnet_corpus_reader.synset_from_pos_and_offset
    return [
        get_synset(pos, offset)._lemmas[lemma_index]
        for pos, offset, lemma_index
        in self._synset._lemma_pointers[self._name, relation_symbol]
    ]
```

After some digging reading the [correct link](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/wngloss7wn) for the [dead link](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wninput.5WN.html#sect3) in the source code, it seems `similar_to` represents all `satellite synsets`, which are clustered terms related by the head synset.

```
satellite synset

Synset in an adjective cluster representing a concept 
that is similar in meaning to the concept represented 
by its head synset
```